# unwanted horizontal scrollbar in Divi Theme

Tags: wordpress, scrollbar, width, horizontal-scrolling, divi

so I am making my first website in WP using Divi Theme and suddenly this horizontal scrollbar shows on 14' screen that hasn't been there before. When I view it on tablet or phone or 17' plus screens there is now scrollbar at all. I am not aware that I have done anything particular for it to be displayed. I tried to check width settings, but it doesn't seem to be the real issue. My website is https://vonofit.cz/en/home/ also as [website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU8wG.png) I would really appreciate any advices as I am beginner to this. Many thanks anyone.

Jan

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a better explanation for the problems, with the code that you tried or the screenshots of the O/p, it will bring more helping hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because something is making the page container larger than the browser window, which makes the scroll bar appear so the user can scroll to see the excess space. I didn't identify what is causing the issue, but an easy fix would be to add a line of css to the stylesheet that will make the page overflow hidden. Something like this should work:

```
div#page-container {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```